# Should there be a separate Windows RT tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

We have a few questions tagged [windows-8](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-8). In dealing with a couple of suggested edits for its tag wiki, the thought occurred to me that there might be some confusion regarding its use in relation to Windows RT.

We don't have any questions about Windows RT yet, but should [windows-8](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-8) be more strongly defined as desktop Windows only?

Comment: I think the obvious solution is to make all [tag:windows-8] questions off-topic :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it should, not only for the obvious backward compatibility reasons, but because that's how Microsoft and the rest of the tech world sees it:

- Wikipedia gives it [a separate article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_RT), although still calls it a "version of Windows 8"
- After a cursory search through tech blogs, I couldn't find any that didnt make the distinction between the two as being anything less than "big", even when they did mention that it's technically a version of Windows 8.
- Microsoft doesn't even acknowledge it's a variant/edition of Windows 8 on their marketing website, [saying](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/windows-rt-faq):

  > Windows RT contains many of the same features as Windows 8, but is a new operating system for thin and light PCs.

So I think we should explicitly specify in the [windows-8](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-8) tag wiki that it's for the currently "desktop" (read: x86-compatible) version of Windows 8 only, and that [windows-rt](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-rt) (should we ever need it) is for the currently "tablet/Surface-specific" (read: ARM-compatible) OS. Something as simple as:

> This tag is for Windows 8 proper; for Windows RT-specific questions, use [windows-rt](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-rt).

Comment: *However*, Windows RT is not **the** operating system for windows tablets - Microsoft has already announced plans to produce a Windows-8 (the full version; google Surface Pro) tablet. While I agree the distinction is necessary, "Tablet" can't be the distinctor, as a Windows Tablet *could also be* Windows 8.

Comment: @RavenDreamer The distinction, if it needs be, needs be between Desktop and "Metro" apps. Win8 vs Win8 RT only muddles things.

Comment: @RavenDreamer I agree; I figured someone would take issue with my overly facile use of the terms. :P I'm more inclined to think the clarifying line should be "This tag is for Windows 8 proper; if your question is about Windows RT, use [tag:windows-rt]" and avoid the whole "which device is it used for" issue entirely.

Comment: I think we definitely need to distinguish between (Home)/Pro/Enterprise and RT.  However, I don't think it'll be too much of an issue until we start seeing Metro interface games that run on both 8 and RT.  Then it's still only an issue when the OS meta-tag is necessary.  So, having said all that, I think your suggesting for the tag wiki is definitely a good start, but could probably use some improvement.  Currently, I don't know how to improve it, so if someone else has some suggestions, speak up.